# Extract Specific Word Out of a Vector of Strings

Tags: string, r

I want to extract the word "COUNTY" from the following vector of strings.  I would like this to extend to difference cases (upper and lower) and different spacing issues that could arise. I have the following vector:

```
COUNTY=c("LAWRENCE COUNTY", "SALT LAKE", "OCEAN COUNTY", "JASPER COUNTY", 
"PIMA", "JACKSON COUNTY", "PORTAGE COUNTY", "SEBASTIAN COUNTY", 
"ORANGE", "BERGEN COUNTY")

             COUNTY
1   LAWRENCE COUNTY
2         SALT LAKE
3      OCEAN COUNTY
4     JASPER COUNTY
5              PIMA
6    JACKSON COUNTY
7    PORTAGE COUNTY
8  SEBASTIAN COUNTY
9            ORANGE
10    BERGEN COUNTY
```

I want this vector to look like this:

```
      COUNTY
1     LAWRENCE
2     SALT LAKE
3     OCEAN
4     JASPER
5     PIMA
6     JACKSON
7     PORTAGE
8     SEBASTIAN
9     ORANGE
10    BERGEN
```

I basically want to strip out the wherever is says "COUNTY".

Comment: I'm pretty sure that while writing you question SO provided you with some suggestions of questions regarding the same problem. It was asked many times before.

Comment: There were quite a few similar suggestions.  But I am not familiar enough with regular expressions to account for all the one-off problems that I have been encountering (which Richard addressed very well).  I apologize for the redundancy.

Comment: Thanks @Mike.Gahan.  Not sure why this post is on hold.  It's perfectly clear to me what you're trying to do.  If you update the post with a more precise explanation and some trial code they may re-open it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `gsub`, if case is known and spacing is known:

```
> gsub(' COUNTY', '', COUNTY, fixed = TRUE)
## [1] "LAWRENCE"  "SALT LAKE" "OCEAN"     "JASPER"    "PIMA"      "JACKSON"  
## [7] "PORTAGE"   "SEBASTIAN" "ORANGE"    "BERGEN"
```

case unknown:

```
> gsub(' county', '', COUNTY, ignore.case = TRUE)
## [1] "LAWRENCE"  "SALT LAKE" "OCEAN"     "JASPER"    "PIMA"      "JACKSON"  
## [7] "PORTAGE"   "SEBASTIAN" "ORANGE"    "BERGEN"
```

spacing and case not known:

```
> gsub('\\s+(county)', '', COUNTY, ignore.case = TRUE)
## [1] "LAWRENCE"  "SALT LAKE" "OCEAN"     "JASPER"    "PIMA"      "JACKSON"  
## [7] "PORTAGE"   "SEBASTIAN" "ORANGE"    "BERGEN"
```

---

Alternatively, this can be done with `strsplit`:

```
> unlist(strsplit(COUNTY, ' COUNTY'))
## [1] "LAWRENCE"  "SALT LAKE" "OCEAN"     "JASPER"    "PIMA"      "JACKSON"  
## [7] "PORTAGE"   "SEBASTIAN" "ORANGE"    "BERGEN"
```